# pgAdmin でバックアップからのレストアができない

Tags: windows, postgresql

**実行環境:**
Windows 11, PostgreSQL 11, pgAdmin 4.30

Windows 11 データベースを新しいパソコンに移植しようとしています。元のパソコンのpgAdmin4でデータベース pckeiba をバックアップし、バックアップファイルの pckeiba_backup3 をもう1台のパソコンでレス
トアすればコピーできるはずなんですが、レストアする段階で以下の表示が出てしまいます。

```
Failed(exit code: 1)
```

前の環境と移植後の環境でオーナーが違うからこう出るのだとか書いてありますが、オプションでownerを保存してもダメなようです。何が悪いのかわかりません。

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin\pg_restore.exe --host "127.0.0.1" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "pckeiba" --no-owner --verbose "C:\Users\shino\PCKEIB~4"

当方データベースはSQLを少しかじった程度です。すいませんがヒントだけでも教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

追伸　ありがとうございます。後にこんな文章がありました。

Start time :Thu Jun 22 2023 23:11:42 GMT+0900(日本標準時）×Stop Process
pg_restore: [�A�[�J�C�o] �t�@�C���w�b�_���̃o�[�W����(1.14)�̓T�|�[�g����Ă��܂���

pgAdmin以外の方法でやったほうがいいのでしょうか？

Comment: おそらくもっとエラーメッセージが出ていると思うのですが、それをすべて質問文に貼っていただけないでしょうか。隠したい部分は隠して頂いて大丈夫です。質問文は後からでも [edit] できます。

Comment: 説明でのバックアップファイルは `pckeiba_backup3` なのにコマンドでは `PCKEIB~4` を指定していますが、こちらは間違いないですか？

Comment: はい。これは間違いないです。表示の問題だと思います。ただbackup3ではなくbackup4でやったので～4になっているのかもしれません